# Lazy initialization page object elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have **PageObject** with 50 elements describing all elements on the page. More than 30 tests use this elements. But how can I use only that elements what I need for test and do not initialize them all.

```
public class DetailReportingPage extends BasePage {

    public static final String PAGE_URL = ReportingPage.PAGE_URL + ":ReportingDetailTab";

    public Button detailSubTabBtn = new Button(By.id("DetailSubTab"));

    public TextField reportNameSelect = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.ReportName-input"));
    public DropDown reportNameDropDown = new DropDown(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.ReportName-trigger"));
    public TextField reportNameInput = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.TextField.ReportName-input"));
    public TextField fileTypeHistory = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.FileType-input"));
    public TextField fileTypeSummary = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.FileType2-input"));
    public TextField valueDate = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.DateField.Element22-input"));
    public TextField curveDate = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.DateField.Element23-input"));

    public CheckBox includeAll = new CheckBox(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.IdAwareCheckBox.Element27"));

    public Button editBtn = new Button(By.xpath("//div[contains(@__gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus,'true')][.//table[contains(@class,'mainTable')]][.//div[text()='Edit']]"));
    public Button deleteBtn = new Button(By.xpath("//div[contains(@__gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus,'true')][.//table[contains(@class,'mainTable')]][.//div[text()='Delete']]"));
    public Button runReportBtn = new Button(By.xpath("//div[contains(@__gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus,'true')][.//table[contains(@class,'mainTable')]][.//div[text()='Run Report']]"));
    public Button mtmHistoryRbtn = new Button(By.xpath("//label[text()='MTM History']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public Button meSummaryRbtn = new Button(By.xpath("//label[text()='ME Summary']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public Button mtmDetailRbtn = new Button(By.xpath("//label[text()='MTM Detail']/preceding-sibling::input"));

    //region for MTM History Type
    public CheckBox cleanMarketValueChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//label[text()='Clean Market Value']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public CheckBox dirtyMarketValueChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//label[text()='(Dirty) Market Value']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public CheckBox cvaChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'ReportMTMHistory')]//label[text()='CVA']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public Button curveDateRbtn = new Button(By.xpath("//label[text()='Curve Date']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public Button staticDateRbtn = new Button(By.xpath("//label[text()='Static Date']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public TextField date = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.DateField.Element17-input"));
    public TextField startDate = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.DateField.StartDate-input"));
    public CheckBox scheduleChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//label[text()='Schedule']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public CheckBox manualInputChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//label[text()='Manual Input']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public CheckBox summaryColumnChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'ReportMTMHistory')]//label[text()='Summary Column']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public CheckBox individualTradeChbx = new CheckBox(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'ReportMTMHistory')]//label[text()='Individual Trade']/preceding-sibling::input"));
    public TextField numOfDates = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.NumberField.#ofDates-input"));
    public TextField frequency = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.Frequency-input"));
    public TextField firstMonth = new  TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.FirstMonth-input"));
    public Table scheduleDates = new Table(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'scroller')]//table/tbody)[4]"));
    public TextField dateField = new TextField(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.ComboBox.Date-input"));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? If you don't want to initialize them all before your test.. Why would you ?

Comment: Have you considered using `Supplier`? `public Supplier<CheckBox> includeAll = () -> new CheckBox(By.id("IR.IrReportingDetailSubTab.IdAwareCheckBox.Element27"));`, and perhaps use caching so that you don't create a new object every single time you're accessing the element.

Comment: Use `PageFactory` and `@FindBy` annotations. It provides lazy instantiation

Comment: As noted above, PageFactory does exactly what you're looking for.